# XPath //* vs //element vs //

Tags: html, xml, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a confusion in finding XPath: When to put `//*` at start and when to put just `//` will work.

For example, I was trying to clear this thing on **https://www.myntra.com/**.  There is one search box thereon the website home page with HTML code

```
<input placeholder="Search" class="desktop-searchBar" value="" data-reactid="529">
```

the below XPath works for this above code

```
//*[@class='desktop-searchBar']
```

I am still confused why I need a `*` after double slash(`//`).

Comment: "Why?" - because the grammar rules say so. Are you asking where in the grammar it says this? Or are you asking why the grammar was designed this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `//*[@class='desktop-searchBar']`

   says to select all elements, *regardless of name*, with an `class` attribute value of `desktop-searchBar`.
2. `//input[@class='desktop-searchBar']`

   says the same as #1 except constrains the element to be named `input`.
3. `//[@class='desktop-searchBar']`

   is *syntactically invalid* in XPath because it's missing a required node test such as `input` (element named `input`) or `*` (any element).